# Webharvest If and null test

Tags: xml, xpath, webharvest

I'm trying to make my program check the return of an xpath expression and if it is null it should try a different one, how do I do this? I have tried all the examples on the website and the blank single quotes will not compile.

```
    <var-def name="googleResults">
    <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/div/text()">
        <html-to-xml>
            <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=asus laptops&amp;hl=en"/>
        </html-to-xml>
    </xpath>
</var-def>

<var-def name="productTruth">
    <case>
        <if condition="${googleResults != null}">
            <var name="googleResults"/>
        </if>
        <else>
            <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/text()">
                <html-to-xml>
                    <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=asus laptops&amp;hl=en"/>
                </html-to-xml>
            </xpath>
        </else>
    </case>
</var-def>
```

Also is there any way to manipulate a defined variable to exclude certain parts of strings like symbols and numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same problem as you, where the example from the [official WH user manual](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#case) does not work, because of double single quotes.

as a work around I use: `variable.toString().length() > 0`

and here is your code:

```
<var-def name="googleResults">
    <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/div/text()">
        <html-to-xml>
            <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=asus laptops&amp;hl=en"/>
        </html-to-xml>
    </xpath>
</var-def>

<var-def name="productTruth">
    <case>
        <if condition="${googleResults.toString().length() > 0}">
            <var name="googleResults"/>
        </if>
        <else>
            <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/text()">
                <html-to-xml>
                    <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=asus laptops&amp;hl=en"/>
                </html-to-xml>
            </xpath>
        </else>
    </case>
</var-def>
```

Also, a few notes on your code in general:

1) Actually downloading the page is the most time and memory - consuming part of web harvest. If the information you want is not collected by the first xpath, you end up re-downloading the page (re-running the http request). save the result of the http request in a variable and you can then re-query the result, without repeating the download - this also limits the number of times you hit the source server, which becomes an issue if you have multiple pages to scrape.

```
    <var-def name="pagetext">
            <html-to-xml>
                <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=asus laptops&amp;hl=en"/>
            </html-to-xml>
    </var-def>

    <var-def name="googleResults">
        <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/div/text()">
            <var name="pagetext"/>
        </xpath>
    </var-def>

    <var-def name="productTruth">
        <case>
            <if condition="${googleResults.toString().length() > 0}">
                <var name="googleResults"/>
            </if>
            <else>
                <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/text()">
                    <var name="pagetext"/>
                </xpath>
            </else>
        </case>
    </var-def>
```

2) you can avoid the whole conditional by changing the xpath:

`//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/descendant-or-self::text()`

```
    <var-def name="pagetext">
            <html-to-xml>
                <http url="http://google.com/shopping?q=asus laptops&amp;hl=en"/>
            </html-to-xml>
    </var-def>

    <var-def name="googleResults">
        <xpath expression="//div[@id='center_col']//div[@id='search']//div[@id='ires']//ol/li/div//b/descendant-or-self::text()">
            <var name="pagetext"/>
        </xpath>
    </var-def>
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me out with an issue I was having with webharvest's `if` function. The syntax `<if condition="${var.toString().length() > 0}">` worked beautifully for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may use normalize-space(.) != '' instead of ${googleResults != null}.

To manipulate a defined variable to exclude certain parts of strings like symbols and numbers use starts-with() ends-with() matches(), contains() any one of them as per your needs and webharvest support.

Take an example to check `<b>dfsdffsnavindfds</b>` element:

1. /b[starts-with(text(), 'd')] -- to find out if it is has starting character 'd'
2. /b[ends-with(text(), 's')] -- to find out it if is has starting character 's'
3. /b[contains(text(), 'navin')] -- to find out if it is has string 'navin'

For more information look at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: How would I use these in the code itself? Forgive me I'm very new to XML and WebHarvest.